# Drag drop and revert in Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to drag and  drop element in a container by retaining its copy at its original location.

My code is as follows

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // sets the draggable
        $('#drag .drg').draggable({
            cursor: 'move',          // sets the cursor apperance
            revert: 'valid'

        });

        // sets droppable
        $('#drop').droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                // after the draggable is droped, hides it with a hide() effect
                ui.draggable.hide(1000);
            }
        });

        // when the "#sw" element (inside the "#drop") is clicked
        // show the items with class "drg", contained in "#drag"
        $('#drop #sw').click(function () {
            $('#drag .drg').slideDown(1000);
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<div id="drop">
    Drop here &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <span id="sw">Show</span></div>
<div id="drag">
    Drag these images:<br />
    <img src="../../Images/1.jpg" alt="circle" width="45" height="45" class="drg" />
    <img src="../../Images/2.jpg" alt="triangle" width="65" height="55" class="drg" />
    <img src="../../Images/3.jpg" alt="rhomb" width="70" height="55" class="drg" />
    <div class="drg">
        DIV with some content. Click and drag</div>
</div>
```

I can drag and drop but i am not able to create copy at  its original location. Also I want to drag and drop in a specified location only.

Thank You All

Answer (score 0):

You can use Draggable interaction from jQuery UI.

This function enables draggable functionality on any DOM element. You can move the draggable object by clicking on it with the mouse and dragging it anywhere within the viewport.

Take a look here:

[Draggable jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: Thank you but This is not what I have asked for